# How can a camera zoom & photograph the sun without damaging the lens?

Tags: visible-light

I find Huge images of sun in google images, i doubt that if we zoom the sun's image by using camera, then definitely sunlight will also get intensified leads to lens damage nothing but acting like magnifying glass.

So How can a camera zoom & photograph the sun without damaging the lens?

Comment: Although it can be interpreted as a physics question, maybe it could have a better place on photo SE (but only a mod can sent it there)

Comment: This question is off-topic to physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy solar filters ([for example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E3QH63G)) which block out most of the radiation including UV, making it safe to photograph.

You can even make your own really cheaply. Buy a roll of [biaxially-oriented polyethylene terephthalate (BoPET)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BoPET), perhaps better known by its brand name Mylar. This will set you back about $15USD:

[image: Mylar roll]

Cut out a circle, attach it to a rim, and you have a bespoke solar filter:

[image]

Then you can get some wonderful shots of the sun including sun spots and the passing of the ISS.